# Seems like some of the resources are old. Check domain availability. PHP

Tags: php

Here is what I currently have to get the list of domains.

```
<?php
$myFile = "domains.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 500);
fclose($fh);
echo nl2br($theData);
?>
```

This fetches the file and lists the domains in an order like:

> Domain.com
>
> Domain2.com
>
> Domain3.com

I want to assign a function for each domain in the list to be ran through a whois query and if available post domain.com - available (later down the road I will have it run a API query to register) and if not available post domain.com - taken

Any idea where to get started?

Answer (score 4):

Well, reading a file with one domain per line into an array of domains is a one-liner.

```
$domains = file('domains.txt');
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
  //run the whois query on $domain
}
```

Comment: Great use of the `file` function. This function is new to me.

Comment: Looks good so far. I can now function then echo the results. Any idea where to start with the function itself. Everything I try seems to post false results or none at all :\

Comment: Get a list of WHOIS servers for the TLDs you're interested in, and implement the WHOIS protocol with PHP sockets. You can go read the source of the `whois` program that comes with every Linux/Unix distribution.

Comment: The above worked great for doing say echo $domain . '<br />'; but any time I try doing a function on $domain it returns array()

Comment: `$domains` is an array, `$domain` is a string. I can't debug the return value of "a function" you haven't shared. If you've written more code and need help with it, you should create a new question.